# Два списка на одном экране

Tags: android, listview, java

Привет всем! У меня есть активити, на котором необходимо расположить 2 кастомных ListView. Каждый итем списка допустим один TextView. При этом, на активити имеется много других компонентов. Экран должен скроллиться полностью. Высота у ListView должна быть wrap_content т.е столько, сколько ему нужно. ListView помещять в ScrollView нельзя, ибо высота у него будет равна одному элементу. Но совсем случайно я нашел решение:

```
public class Utility {
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {

        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

}

Использовать его просто:

```
Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lv);
```

Насколько я понял, этот метод пробегается по каждому элементу списка, суммирует высоту каждого итема и затем уже устанавливает полученную высоту в ListView. Да, я понимаю, что код не совсем правильный ибо мы получаем каждую вьюшку заного и это не правильно и т. д, но у меня в списках максимальное число элементов 5, поэтому мне это подходит.

Так вот, в чем вопрос, все работает отлично до тех пор, пока ТекстВью находящийся в списке имеет высоту одну строку, если текст будет длинный, то часть списка обрезается. Возможно кто-нибудь подскажет как с этим бороться. Спасибо.

Comment: я бы ради 5 елементов не делал листвью. Положил бы их в линеар лаяут, и все...

Comment: если у меня 2 списка в активити, мне нужно ко второму списку добавить в хедер ListView1? либо к первому добавить второй и все остальное? мне не подходит.

Comment: А зачем вам фон у списка? Сделайте фон для каждого элемента отдельно, а ListView транспарентным! А чтобы мы дали Вам подробный ответ выложите изображение того как это должно выглядеть!

Comment: не фон у списка, а стилизация списка. закругленные границы, обводка и т д

Comment: ну, извините, что я не телепат, и не читаю ваших мыслей...

Comment: Если один список должен продолжать второй, то почему не сделать из них один список, и адаптер, и в onCreateView() определять, какой именно xml инфлировать?

Comment: Покажите XML вашего layout'а.

Answer (score 1):

Эта задача решается при помощи одного `ListView` с несколькими адаптерами, в следствии чего создаётся эффект нескольких `ListView`.

Посмотрите в сторону отличной библиотеки от небезызвестного Mark Murphy (aka commonsguy) — [CWAC MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) — она делает ровно то, что вы хотите. И делает это хорошо.

Небольшой пример использования всего этого дела:

```
MergeAdapter adapter = new MergeAdapter();
adapter.addAdapter(new YourFirstAdapter());
adapter.addAdapter(new YourSecondAdapter());
yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: спасибо за совет, но мне не хотелось бы использовать сторонюю библиотеку. нужно пол дня чтобы разобраться в ней, и еще столько же, чтобы переделать то, что у меня реализовано сейчас. да и я почему-то сомневаюсь, что это именно то, что мне нужно. я не сказал, что у списков разные адаптеры, разная разметка, разное положение на активити.

Comment: из того, что вы сказали понятно только, что у вас 2 списка... и все...

Comment: @kanarisisgod, полагаю, вы ведь даже не прошли по ссылке, верно? И прилагающийся сэмпл не глянули. Иначе не продолжали бы доказывать, что это не то, что вам нужно. Из того, что вы выше в комментарии перечислили в качестве контраргументов, ничего таковым не является.

Comment: прошел. даже импортировал в проект и немного поигрался. все компоненты нужно создавать динамически, насколько я понял (кнопки, лейблы). если разметить их в xml - то они не будут скроллится вместе со списком. а уменя на активити больше 30ти компонентов - и все создавать динамически?

Comment: С чего вы это всё взяли? Ничего динамически создавать не нужно. Достаточно лишь взять свой адаптер и добавить его в `MergeAdapter`. И всё. И прилагающийся сэмпл именно это и демонстрирует. Вы бы хоть посмотрели его повнимательнее, там всего то один класс на 150 строк, в чём сложность сесть, потратить пять минут и разобраться наконец?

Comment: но ведь те компоненты, который созданы в xml до ListView и после не будут скроллитться. скроллиться будет только список.

Comment: Ну да, компоненты не в `ListView` не будут скроллиться, а с чего бы должны? Для этого, как вам @metalurgus выше посоветовал, есть header и footer у `ListView`. А вообще, показали бы уже, как вам выше писали, как должен выглядеть желаемый результат.

Comment: То, что вы показали, отлично делается одним `ListView` и одним адаптером, тут даже никаких вспомогательных библиотек не нужно, и костылей, наподобие вышеприведённого `Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren` так же. И сами комментарии, и кнопка "Перейти к комментариям", и все остальные элементы — элементы `ListView`, в адаптере которого, в зависимости от каких-то условий, инфлэйтится тот или иной `layout`. Всего лишь. И никаких надуманных сложностей.

Comment: > если я добавлю какие либо компоненты в хедер, то они будут находится внутри списка и примут его стиль

Тоже неверно. Стилизуйте элементы списка, а не сам список. И об этом вам, кстати, тоже уже писали выше.